# Running Balance

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I want to design a report in SSRS to capture following.

```
 Running balance               No of Accounts   Running Balance
 From             To        
 -                   99.99      
 100.00             249.99      
 250.00             499.99      
 500.00             999.99      
 1,000.00         1,999.99      
 2,000.00         2,999.99      
 3,000.00         4,999.99      
 5,000.00         6,999.99      
 7,000.00         8,999.99      
 9,000.00         9,999.00      
 10,000.00       14,999.99      
 15,000.00       19,999.00      
 25,000.00       29,999.99      
 30,000.00       34,999.99      
 35,000.00       39,999.99      
 40,000.00       44,999.99      
 50,000.00       59,999.99      
 60,000.00       74,999.99      
 75,000.00       84,999.00      
 85,000.00       99,999.99      
 100,000.00      109,999.99         
 125,000.00      199,999.99         
 Above           200,000.00
```

I'm confused on how to prepare the select statement for this. Data can be taken using a single table.

I used below query,

```
DECLARE @LBrCode AS INT = 2

SELECT 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN A.ActTotBalFcy <= 99.99 THEN A.PrdAcctId END) ,
    SUM(CASE WHEN A.ActTotBalFcy <= 99.99 THEN A.ActTotBalFcy END)
FROM 
    D009022 A
WHERE 
    Substring(A.PrdAcctId, 1, 8) IN ( '20060000', '20060001', '20060002','20060003','20060004', '20060007' )
    AND A.LBrCode = @LBrCode
```

Since there will be more case statements I'm hoping there should be a different approach.

Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with SSRS 2012 I used to develop report like this , But I use date in rank

So. I suggest you to create temporary table to store rank Because I must get all rank data
Example

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp (valueFrom int , valueTo int, val_Flag NVARCHAR(500))
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES(0,99.99,'0-99.99')
```

after created you will have 3 column. like this below

```
valueFrom         valueTo       val_Flag
-----------------------------------------------
    0              99.99        '0-9.99'
    100.00         249.99       '100.00-249.00'
```

Then join table that you want to count

For Example

```
SELECT t.valFrom
    ,t.valTo
    ,t.val_flag
    ,val.cnt
    ,val.[sum]
FROM #tmp t
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT qry.*
        ,CASE 
            WHEN qry.cnt BETWEEN 100.00 AND 249.99 THEN '100.00-249.99'
            WHEN qry.cnt BETWEEN 0 AND 99.99 THEN '0-99.99'
        END AS [join]
    FROM (
        SELECT COUNT(value) AS [cnt]
            ,SUM(value) AS [sum]
        FROM tbl
    ) qry
) val ON val.cnt BETWEEN t.valFrom AND t.valTo
```

So, It's just my guideline

Hope this help.

Comment: Creating temp table is not possible

Answer (score 0):

The following is a simple solution, without your custom ranges.  I haven't used SSRS very much, but I assuming it will allow you to merge your groupings together in some way.  Otherwise, you will need case statements for each one

``` WITH L0 AS (SELECT 1 N UNION ALL SELECT 1),
    L1 AS (SELECT 1 N FROM L0, L0 B),
    L2 AS (SELECT 1 N FROM L1, L1 B),
    L3 AS (SELECT 1 N FROM L2, L2 B),
    L4 AS (SELECT 1 N FROM L3, L3 B),
    Nums AS (SELECT 250*(Row_Number() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1))) Num FROM L4)
``
    SELECT 
    (Num-250) AS [FROM],
    Num AS [TO]
    COUNT(*) AS No_Accts,
    SUM(A.ActTotBalFcy) AS Running_Balance
    FROM Nums INNER JOIN D009022 A on A.ActTotBalFcy < Num AND A.ActTotBalFcy >= Num-250
    GROUP BY Nums.Num ```